# How can i configure deltaSpike data in a EJB module?

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, deltaspike

I'm new using DeltaSpike data, the idea is work with something like spring-data but just with CDI and EJBs. I created some example in a java web project and the test was successful, but now I need to do the same thing in an EJB module, but it doesn't work. Know somebody if is necessary an additional configuration to make work DeltaSpike data in an EJB module?

I used the tutorial in this link:

http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/data.html

Sorry for my english, I'm still learning.

Comment: If you ask such questions on their Mailing-List, you will get answers way faster.